# Rails scope with a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I work on a project and I bumb into a scope use that I didn't know. 
I have those two definitions :

```
Class Mymodel
scope :active, where({ active: true })

Class SecondModel
has_many :mymodel
```

And then I used them like :

```
instance_var = SecondModel.new
instance_var.mymodels.active
```

This thing actually works my question is if it's a good way of doing it and 
how does it work since the scope is equivalent with a class method ?
I use mongoid for the database part.

Answer (score 2):

It works because
`instance_var.mymodels` can be a `Mongoid::Criteria` instance.

So it can accept all scopes of `Mymodel`.

Now the practical difference between scopes and class methods in `ActiveRecord` (and as far as I remember the same goes for `Mongoid`) is that scopes must return a relation.

There is no problem in using relations and scopes that way, actually it is very logical and it is the way we normally use them.